# An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using a disconnected Entity Framework 4 Object Context and thanks to some awesome help previously, I've moved forward.

Now, I have more problems. It seems EF seems to create unnecessary barriers when performing simple CRUD. In this case parent-child relations.

In my situation, I have an existing VatCode which has VatRates. I load this in, display it and allow the user to add more VatRates. So we end up with:

> VatCode --- VatRate (existing)
>            +- VatRate (added by user)

Saving this using the following code:

```
using (SopEntities sopEntities = EntitiesFactory.Create()) {
   VatRepository vatRepository = new VatRepository(sopEntities);

   foreach (VatRate vatRate in Item.VatRates) {
      if (vatRate.EntityKey == null || vatRate.EntityKey.IsTemporary) {
         sopEntities.VatRates.Attach(vatRate); 
         sopEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(
            vatRate,
            System.Data.EntityState.Added
         );
      } else {
         sopEntities.VatRates.Attach(vatRate); // exception here
         sopEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(
            vatRate,
            System.Data.EntityState.Modified
         );
      }
   }

   if (IsNew) {
      sopEntities.VatCodes.AddObject(Item);
   } else {
      sopEntities.VatCodes.Attach(Item);
      sopEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Item,System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
   }
   vatRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, when I save I get the exception:

> An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an
>   object context

I have attached a screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

I am manually attaching/adding VatRates within the collection myself to try and identify which object is at issue. However, this does not help. THe exception shown is on the *genuine* existing VatRate within the VatCode, which *already has* an Entity Key. Could it be that the EF is stepping up the object graph into the VatCode and back down into the other VatRate which hasn't been set-up yet - because I haven't yet got to it?

Basically, how can I save the VatCode and the VatRates contained within it within a disconnected scenario?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. And the net result is that now the new VatRate doesn't get added at all :( But, no exception!

Comment: Strange... I have no idea what's going on. The only thing I see is that you have a redundant `ChangeObjectState(..., Added)` after `AddObject` (in the screenshot, in the code snippet you have an `Attach`, a typo I guess) but it shouldn't play a role.

Comment: Whoops. Yes, that was a typo. Between versionf of code that is running and prepared for the post I guess I made an error. I'm losing confidence in doing things properly with this! Can't beat an enterprise ORM in front of a set of manual joins through multiple SELECTS :(. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

When I found this error, was because my object was under static modifier and in another context.

You may check your code for this situation.
Hope this helps :)